# VirtualBox state can not be saved

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I can not save the state of my VM, but get the below error. What can I do?

- **Host:** Linux Kubuntu 14.4
- **Guest:** Windows 7
- **Error Message:**

  The state of the virtual Machine MyWindows7 can not be saved.

  Error code:VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)

I read about a similar case in http://www.deltalounge.net/wpress/2011/08/virtualbox-solved-vbox_e_file_error-0x80bb0004/ and the thread https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=57889 also discusses this kind of error, though in a different context, but I am not sure how to proceed in my case. I tried to use CHKDSK from my virtual Windows according to https://askleo.com/chkdsk_what_is_it_and_how_do_i_run_it/ running `CHKDSK` as administrator only gave the answer that no error were found. I looked at http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/fsck-command-examples/ to see how to run `fsck` from Linux, but couldn't find an example to run it on a file containing a virtual disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your VirtualBox settings. The folder for the **snapshots** may not be correct.

Comment: Can be the global VirtualBox snapshot folder setting, or the VM one